# removeEventListener is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am working on a script which requires me to create rating handles for providing rating of some statements by dragging them on a slider. I am able to add an eventlistener to the objects but not able to remove that.

Below is the code that I am using to add and remove events.

Function to call addDrag method as it requires parameters.

```
var setDrag = function () {
    addDrag(box, bar);
}
```

Function to add mousedown and mouseup events to "box" element

```
bindEvents(box, "mousedown", setDrag);
bindEvents(box, "mouseup", setDrag);
bindEvents(document, "mouseup", setDrag);
```

addDrag method:

```
var addDrag = function (elBox, elBar) {
    var mouseStartPosition = event.clientX;
    var boxInitMouseAndLeftGap = mouseStartPosition - elBox.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var barInitMouseAndLeftGap = mouseStartPosition - elBar.getBoundingClientRect().left;

    var dragHandle = function () {
        elBox.style.left = (event.clientX - mouseStartPosition - boxInitMouseAndLeftGap) + "px";
        elBar.style.left = (event.clientX - mouseStartPosition - barInitMouseAndLeftGap) + "px";
    };

    if (event.type == "mousedown") {
        bindEvents(document, "mousemove", dragHandle);
    }

    //HERE WE NEED TO REMOVE THE DRAG FUNCTIONALITY WHEN MOUSEUP IS TRIGGERED ON BOX OR DOCUMENT, THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING FOR ME.
    else if (event.type == "mouseup"){
        unbindEvents(document, "mousemove", dragHandle);
    }
}
```

Below are the customized functions to add and remove events for cross browser workaround:

```
function bindEvents(el, action, func) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {                    // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
        el.addEventListener(action, func);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {                  // For IE 8 and earlier versions
        el.attachEvent("on" + action, func);
    }
    return el;
}

function unbindEvents(el, action, func) {
    if (el.removeEventListener) {                    // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
        el.removeEventListener(action, func);
    } else if (el.detachEvent) {                  // For IE 8 and earlier versions
        el.detachEvent("on" + action, func);
    }
    return el;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `el.removeEventListener(action, func, false)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: It won't work because your `dragHandle` function is created as a new function instance each time you call `addDrag()`. Even though it's the same code, it's a new object, and so `removeEventListener()` will not find the new function as an existing event handler. You'll have to rearrange the code to ensure that `dragHandle` always refers to exactly the same function instance.

Comment: yeah Pointy, your suggestion has worked :). Thanks!